# What does 302 redirects as filters mean?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, http-status-code-302

I have an hosting account on Godaddy which has been redirected for last few days, to be precise, 5 days.

After mailing them quite few times, this is what they had to say

> The 302 redirects are filters setup to maintain the integrity of the hosting server while we investigate and resolve an issue(s)

The post is not for boo-haa of godaddy, all I want to know is the technical aspect of the above term.

**Why these filters are set, how they are set and what purpose they fulfill**

Any sort of detailing on the issue will be helpful. Being a developer, it will only help when I plan to roll out hosting on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter was set by godaddy to restrict access to your account until they can complete an investigation. The why would depend but if your website had illegal content on it whether you put it there, a user of yours or your account was hacked and someone else did would be some possible whys. By illegal I mean anything in violation of their policies or the law. The purpose is to protect their network and or you in the event that someone else is responsible for whatever they are investigating. I would call them.

Comment: my site doesn't offer any sort of membership to anonymous users ....though there is just an admin panel for updation of website....Content is all but legal....I can't assume any hack because everything is same as before and I am able to visit my website from here.....This is the [Link](http://price-tag.org), see if the redirection is happening for you too.....BTW does it take this long to investigate if something is suspicious

Comment: I have viewed the source code of the main page and it looks rather clean. Does not "seem" to be anything funny going on. There are really a number of reasons they would apply a filter to redirect you. The ones I listed were what came to mind first. I would really give them a call. Are you still unable to view the site? Edit: I did just see that you said your website "is" accessible via that link provided. Do you have a link to the website via the domain you are getting the 302 redirect on?

Comment: I checked my website on [facebook debug tool: Here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fprice-tag.org%2F) and on this [Redirect check website](http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/). Also, some of my overseas users can't visit the website..... Were you able to visit the website without any redirect ??

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes I was able to see your website just fine and it didn't redirect for me. I am still able to see it without any redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of pulling my website from Godaddy because of the same reason. They will randomly run a 302 redirect filter to protect their server. I found about 1/3 of my potential customers were being redirected to a non working version of my website. I spoke with a support staff at Godaddy and they had no reason but it is designed to protect their system. This is what you should look for. I use a company called Stat Counter and it shows your visitors paths my web address is www.actions4photographers.com What Go daddy does is take my web address and add 4-or 5 letters to the end of it and redirecting my customers to a non working version of my site. 
I have had customers tell me my site was not functioning and I spent a small fortune trying to find out why. Now I know. Trying to get GoDaddy to admit that they were running the 302 redirect filters was like pulling hens teeth. I have been spending... like most of you a lot of time and money working on getting traffic to find out they are just turning away 1/3 of my traffic. How it this fair?